# Always getting interesting Segmentation Fault with g++

Tags: c++, data-structures, g++

I am working on simple linked list project, everything works fine except List class destructor. I am trying to delete every Node that list has but g++ throws Segmentation Fault everytime(even for empty destructor). Can someone help me, what is wrong with my code? Thanks!.

My List header;

```
struct Node{
   double data;
   Node* next;
};

class List{
public:
    List();
    ~List();

    void insertF(double data);
    void printList();

private:
    Node* head;
    Node* currNode;
};
```

List source file;

```
#include "List.h"

List::List(){
    std::cout<<"Constructed Linked List";
}

void List::insertF(double dataX){
  
  Node* nn = new Node;

  if(!currNode){
    head = nn;
    nn->data=dataX;
    currNode = nn;
  }else{
    currNode->next = nn;
    nn->data = dataX;
    currNode = nn;
  }


}

void List::printList(){
   Node* walker = head;

   while(walker){
    std::cout<<walker->data;
    std::cout<<"----->";
    walker = walker->next;
   }
}

List::~List(){
   
    Node* currNode = head, *nextNode = NULL;
    while(currNode != NULL){
        nextNode = currNode->next;
        delete currNode;
        currNode = nextNode;
    }
    std::cout<<"sd";

}
```

Main;

```
#include "List.h"
using namespace std;


int main(){
  List list;


  list.insertF(3.0);
  list.insertF(4.0);
  list.printList();

}
```

Even;

```
List::~List(){
    std::cout<<"sd";

}
```

Throws segmentation fault. List is always filled so I dont check if head is empty

Comment: You dont seem to initialize  your member variables in your constructor (or at declaration C++17).

Comment: Member currNode in your linked list makes zero sense. Seems it should be named tail instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by using values of the member variables `head` and `currNode` without initialization.

Initialize them like this:

```
List::List(){
    head = nullptr; // add this
    currNode = nullptr; // add this
    std::cout<<"Constructed Linked List";
}
```

Or like this:

```
List::List() : head(nullptr), currNode(nullptr) { // add member initialization list
    std::cout<<"Constructed Linked List";
}
```

Comment: I thought uninitialized pointers are always nullptr or NULL type, it works, thank you.

Comment: *I thought uninitialized pointers are always nullptr or NULL type* -- Why would a pointer be a specific value if it's uninitialized?

Comment: First method really shouldn't be recommeded. Initialization section or direct member initialization should be the only things used.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It should be because it is defined so in the environment (for example, uninitialized variable may set to value that stand for "uninitialized" in debug mode). Value of uninitialized variables are indeteminate, according to the standard ([N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 8.5 Initializers 11)

Comment: @MikeCAT I was actually asking Bcrx the question.  I am quite aware that uninitialized means the value can be anything.

Comment: I saw somewhere that uninitialized pointers always initialized to nullptr type by compiler for error prevention purposes, maybe I remember it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You have not initialized `currNode` anywhere, so when you do:

```
if(!currNode) {
```

the first time `insertF` is called, this use of `currNode` invokes undefined behavior.

You should initialize all your members like this:

```
Node* head = nullptr;
Node* currNode = nullptr;
```

Comment: That worked, but interesting thing is when I completely delete destructor the code works without initilization that is why I am confused.

Comment: UB means anything can happen. I know it can seem weird that changing seemingly unrelated code can affect the program, but that's just the nature of UB.